# JUnit Spring Boot Application - Could not autowire fields

Tags: java, spring, junit, jhipster

I have small app written with JHipster code generator with Spring Boot on back-end.

For my app I'm trying to write some simple unit/integration tests but I have an error: `Could not autowire. No beans of <type> found`. I'm using IntelliJ IDE, latest version. Here is my piece of code:

```
package com.logate.adminpanel.web.rest;

import com.logate.adminpanel.CrmScoringApp; import
com.logate.adminpanel.repository.CityRepository; import
com.logate.adminpanel.service.CityService; import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith; import
org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration; import
org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration; import
org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.inject.Inject;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = CrmScoringApp.class)
@WebAppConfiguration 
public class CityRestTest { 

     @Inject
     private CityService cityService;

     @Inject
     private CityRepository cityRepository;

     @Test
     public void test()
     {
         Assert.isNull(null);
     }
 }
```

I can't figure it out what is the problem here.

Here is my boot application class:

```
package com.logate.adminpanel;

import com.logate.adminpanel.config.Constants;
import com.logate.adminpanel.config.JHipsterProperties;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import   org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {    MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ JHipsterProperties.class, LiquibaseProperties.class })
public class CrmScoringApp {

    private static final Logger log =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrmScoringApp.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Main method, used to run the application.
     *
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws UnknownHostException if the local host name could not be resolved into an address
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
         SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(CrmScoringApp.class);
         SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
         addDefaultProfile(app, source);
         Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
    log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
            "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
            "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" +
            "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
        env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
        env.getProperty("server.port"),
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
        env.getProperty("server.port"));
}

/**
 * If no profile has been configured, set by default the "dev" profile.
 */
private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
    if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") &&
            !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")) {

        app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes admin_panel.
 * <p>
 * Spring profiles can be configured with a program arguments --spring.profiles.active=your-active-profile
 * <p>
 * You can find more information on how profiles work with JHipster on <a href="http://jhipster.github.io/profiles/">http://jhipster.github.io/profiles/</a>.
 */
@PostConstruct
public void initApplication() {
    if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
        log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
    } else {
        log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
        Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        if (activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! " +
                "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
        }
        if (activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! " +
                "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is city repository class:

```
package com.logate.adminpanel.repository;

import com.logate.adminpanel.domain.City;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

/**
 * Spring Data JPA repository for the City entity.
 */
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City,Long> {

}
```

and here is city service class:

```
package com.logate.adminpanel.service;

import com.logate.adminpanel.domain.City;
import com.logate.adminpanel.repository.CityRepository;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.inject.Inject;

/**
 * Service Implementation for managing City.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class CityService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CityService.class);

    @Inject
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    /**
     * Save a city.
     *
     * @param city the entity to save
     * @return the persisted entity
     */
    public City save(City city) {
        log.debug("Request to save City : {}", city);
        City result = cityRepository.save(city);

        return result;
}


    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<City> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Cities");
        Page<City> result = cityRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public City findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get City : {}", id);
        City city = cityRepository.findOne(id);
        return city;
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete City : {}", id);
        cityRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 30.66   sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.logate.adminpanel.web.rest.CityResourceIntTest
firstTest(com.logate.adminpanel.web.rest.CityResourceIntTest)  Time   elapsed: 0.018 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at     org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDeleg    ate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at     org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplication    Context(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at     org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionL    istener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
        at     org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
        at      org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(Te    stContextManager.java:228)
        at     org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest    (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
        at     org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Console error link: `https://jpst.it/OJM6`

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which `<type>` of beans it can't find?

Comment: CityService and CityRepository

Comment: Could you edit your question to add both of those? Or upload the sample project to somewhere like github

Comment: Try to remove `@WebAppConfiguration` and replace with `@ContextConfiguration` in your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is caused by: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state`. Usually it occurs when port used by tomcat is already in use. Try to change `server.port` in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` file

Comment: I have tried this but it won't work. An exception is thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Have you enabled jpa repositories in your project?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a full stack of your error log

Comment: where can I enable it and how?

Comment: Just search for `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your project. If there is no such annotation, then you definitely should add it.

Comment: It's hard to guess what can be wrong with your config. It would be great if you could share the error log.

Comment: how to share it and where?

Comment: Your exception is caused by: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state`. Usually it occurs when port used by tomcat is already in use. Try to change server.port in `src/test/resources/config/application.yml` file

Comment: you're totally right. Now test works fine. You can write an answer so I can check it as correct.

Comment: I'm glad that it works. Please add the stack trace with `java.lang.IllegalStateException` to your question,  so the others also could see it.

Answer (score 1):

your stackstrace is telling your com.logate.adminpanel.web.rest.CityResourceIntTest test is failing, not your CityRestTest.

If you want to have your tests be available to `gradle test` (which is **very** recommended if you're using CI/CD systems), the class names have to follow a nameconvention, containing "XXXIntTest" or "XXXUnitTest"...

I would look to your CityResourceIntTest, since the failure is there...and rename your rest test to the proper nameconvention.

Comment: I have renamed my class to CityResourceIntTest but I forgot to rename it in my question. Error is the same again.

Comment: CityResourceIntTest.firstTest » IllegalState Failed to load ApplicationContext